# How to remove item offset with an invisible item frame?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

When you make an item frame invisible any item in it has a 1/16 of a block offset so it sits almost flush with the surface it's on.
Is there a way to remove this?

[image]

Comment: I don't think your question is entirely clear. What is the ultimate outcome you want?

Comment: to remove the height change that applies for some reason when item frames are made invisible. Look at the picture for reference.